# StateListAnimator w/ AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-animation, android-appbarlayout

I have a problem with applying elevation value to AppBarLayout.

I know, that the code to apply constant elevation value looks lite this:

```
stateListAnimator.addState(IntArray(0), ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(layoutAppBar, "elevation", someElevationValue))
layoutAppBar.stateListAnimator = stateListAnimator
```

So I placed this code inside **layoutAppBar.addOnOffsetChangedListener** and update elevation value:

```
val appBarElevationCurrent = (currentPercent * appBarElevationMax) / 100
stateListAnimator.addState(IntArray(0), ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(layoutAppBar, "elevation", appBarElevationCurrent))
layoutAppBar.stateListAnimator = stateListAnimator
```

And in that case the elevation value doesn't change. Do you have any thoughts how I can make it work.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out, that initialization of stateListAnimator

```
val stateListAnimator = StateListAnimator()
```

Must be inside listener.
The full code snippet:

```
 layoutAppBar.addOnOffsetChangedListener { _, verticalOffset ->
            val currentPercent = Math.abs(verticalOffset) * 100 / Math.abs(layoutAppBar.totalScrollRange + 1)
            val appBarElevationCurrent = (currentPercent * appBarElevationMax) / 100

            val stateListAnimator = StateListAnimator()
            stateListAnimator.addState(IntArray(0), ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(layoutAppBar, "elevation", appBarElevationCurrent))
            layoutAppBar.stateListAnimator = stateListAnimator
        }
```